# How to install ginkgo and gomega using gopkg?

Tags: go, ginkgo, gomega

I am trying to install [ginkgo](http://onsi.github.io/ginkgo/) and [gomega](http://onsi.github.io/gomega/) using the [gopkg](https://gopkg.in/onsi/gomega.v1). 
It is throwing the following error:

```
src/gopkg.in/onsi/ginkgo.v1/ginkgo_dsl.go:24:2: use of internal package not allowed
src/gopkg.in/onsi/ginkgo.v1/ginkgo_dsl.go:25:2: use of internal package not allowed
src/gopkg.in/onsi/ginkgo.v1/ginkgo_dsl.go:26:2: use of internal package not allowed
src/gopkg.in/onsi/ginkgo.v1/ginkgo_dsl.go:27:2: use of internal package not allowed
src/gopkg.in/onsi/ginkgo.v1/ginkgo_dsl.go:28:2: use of internal package not allowed
src/gopkg.in/onsi/ginkgo.v1/ginkgo_dsl.go:29:2: use of internal package not allowed

src/gopkg.in/onsi/gomega.v1/gomega_dsl.go:21:2: use of internal package not allowed
src/gopkg.in/onsi/gomega.v1/gomega_dsl.go:22:2: use of internal package not allowed
src/gopkg.in/onsi/gomega.v1/gomega_dsl.go:23:2: use of internal package not allowed
```

Comment: What is the actual command you are executing?

Comment: @mbuechmann `go get gopkg.in/onsi/ginkgo.v1` and `go get gopkg.in/onsi/gomega.v1`

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, this is not a fatal error. I was able to download both `ginkgo` and `gomega` using `gopkg` even though I got the same warning messages. A brief look at the source code shows that `gomega_dsl.go` and `ginkgo_dsl.go` import code from an `internal` subdirectory. I do not see why that should be a problem, though. Getting the packages worked despite these warnings.

Answer (score -1):

As per my understanding, you are using `get` instead of `install`.

You can use

- `go install github.com/onsi/ginkgo/ginkgo@latest`
- `go install github.com/onsi/gomega@latest`